# Editor tools missing

Tags: support

I am not getting the editor tools (insert image, format text and so on) for the answer box any more. Does anyone else have this problem? On other SX sites this is not an issue for me. At the moment I have to use markdown which is a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: try a hard refresh of the page and clear your browser cache, this sounds a bit like a broken copy of the SE javascript.

Comment: I have tried that a number of times. Otherwise I wouldn't ask. Whats strange about it is that it works for the other sites.

Comment: Check the JS console if there are any error messages in there. I don't have that problem here, so this doesn't seem to be a general issue.

Comment: I got it. This happens only, when I load the page via https. The toolbar is loaded from a http (not secure) and gets blocked. If I load the page via http, then everything is normal.

Comment: https is not supported, if you use the HTTPSAnywhere extension or anything similar you have to disable it for SE or some stuff will just break. SSL support is planned for some unspecified date in the future, but right now it just breaks some essential functionality.

Comment: I noticed that :-)  Its deactivated now.